# How to convert CSS with properties to MaterialUI Styles in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have the following CSS:

```
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text)
}
```

which allows to show a placeholder inside a content-editable div when it has no content. I am using Material-UI Styles, so I need something like:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  div[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before: {
    content:attr(data-text)
  }
});
```

How could I achieve this? Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below are a couple syntax options depending on whether you want to specify the class directly on the div (`editableDiv`) or on an ancestor element (`container`). The only difference between the two is the space after `&` when targeting descendants.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    "& [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before": {
      content: "attr(data-text)"
    }
  },
  editableDiv: {
    "&[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before": {
      content: "attr(data-text)"
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div contentEditable data-text="Click here to edit div 1" />
        <div contentEditable data-text="Click here to edit div 2" />
      </div>
      <div
        className={classes.editableDiv}
        contentEditable
        data-text="Click here to edit div 3"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Editable div JSS]

Related documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule

Comment: Thank you, It is working. Also thank you for the documentation, I will take a look.