# How do I convert the nested CSS using Material-UI's CSS in JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe, material-ui

I have the following code fo embedding an `iframe`

```js
<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/66140585' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
```

I am using `makeStyles` and I want to know how to write rules for

```css
.embed-container iframe, 
.embed-container object, 
.embed-container embed { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work

```js
embedContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    border: "6px solid yellow"
  }

embedContainer iframe: { 
position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct syntax (though not executed, so possibility of minor syntax errors):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  embedContainer: {
    "& iframe, & object, & embed": {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
    }
  }
});
```

Related answers and documentation:

- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule
- [how to use css in JS for nested hover styles, Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716926/how-to-use-css-in-js-for-nested-hover-styles-material-ui/57729101#57729101)
- [In Material UI, How can I override a selector selected component style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724968/in-material-ui-how-can-i-override-a-selector-selected-component-style/54726562#54726562)
- [Simple selector and nested selector in JSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326638/simple-selector-and-nested-selector-in-jss/58330371#58330371)
- [How to convert CSS with properties to MaterialUI Styles in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326571/how-to-convert-css-with-properties-to-materialui-styles-in-reactjs/59326870#59326870)